# Specialization of a class that uses Policy classes

Tags: c++, templates, specialization

I wrote the following:

```
//Policy Classes
template
<typename T>
struct CheckForZeroSpeed
{
};


template
<typename T>
struct NoCheck
{
};

//Specialization for one of the Policy Classes
template
<>
struct NoCheck<float>
{
};


//Class that uses Policy
template
<typename T,template <class C> class Policy>
class Base : public Policy<T>
{

};

//Inherited class that uses Policy
template
<typename T,template <class C> class Policy>
class Derived : public Base<T,Policy>
{
};
```

**How can I declare a specialization of the Base class (let's say for the `int` type) and a specialization  for the Derived class?**

This also works:

```
template
<>
class Base<int,NoCheck>
{
};
```

But this is a specialization based both on the type and the policy, is it a way to have specialization based only one (type) of the two template parameters? Something like:

```
//not compile
template
<template <class C> class Policy>
class Base<int,Policy<T>>
{
};
```

**Edit:**
The correct is:

```
//Partial specialization based on the type
    template
    <template <class C> class Policy>
    class Base<int,Policy>
    {
    };

//Partial specialization based on the Policy

    template
    <typename T>
    class Base<T,NoCheck>
    {
    };
```

Comment: `Policy<int>` maybe? There's no T in template arguments, where do you expect it to come from?

Comment: I know that Policy<T> doesn't work, ofcouse. `Policy<int>` doesn't work too. I wrote the last as an example, I am wondering how can I declare it, it's not a declaration.